# Detect if a given file is gzip or TarGzip

Tags: file, gzip, tar, file-type

Given a file, using the magic sequence, I can detect with compression type it belongs to.
But magic sequence for gzip and tarGzip is the same.
So, how can I differentiate between these 2 file types.

On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures , we can see that the file signature for both these files is hexadecimal **1f 8b**

Comment: Did you try using `file <filename>`?

Comment: A tgz file is simply a tar file that has been compressed with gzip. So you need to uncompress it to find out what the original type was.

Comment: `gzcat filename | file -`

Comment: @Dominique That just says that it's a compressed file, it doesn't recurse into the original file's type.

Comment: `gzip -l file.tgz | sed '2!d' | grep -q '\.tar$' && echo "file is a tar.gz"`?

Comment: Oh, just discovered the `-z` option to `file` -- it looks inside compressed files.

Answer (score 1):

Decompress the first 1K bytes and check the tar checksum on the first 512 of those. If that matches, it is very likely you are dealing with a tar file. (If there aren't 1024 bytes, then it isn't a tar file.)